# Does type II sum of squares gives a different r2, slope, and intercept of linear regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression

if so, the R package car does not provides the results of r2, slope and intercept. How to extract them?

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                   y = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10.5))
model <- lm(y~x, data = df)
Anova(model, type="II")
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: The difference among type I, II and III sums of squares is which models or sub-models they compare. The models themselves, are not changed.

Comment: Try `summary(model)` - does that contain the information you need?

Comment: "Does type II sum of squares gives a different r2, slope, and intercept of linear regression?": Compared to what?  The best answer we can give at the moment, based on the information you've provided, is "sometimes".

Answer (score 0):

Linear model parameters and r2 are the same and can be extracted with the standard `summary` function:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 y = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10.5))
model <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
summary(model)
```

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5 
 1.000e-01  1.443e-15 -1.000e-01 -2.000e-01  2.000e-01 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.20000    0.19149  -1.044    0.373    
x            2.10000    0.05774  36.373 4.57e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1826 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9977,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.997 
F-statistic:  1323 on 1 and 3 DF,  p-value: 4.57e-05
```

A difference may occur for **sums of squares**, and therefore F- and p-values in the unbalanced case. The `Anova` function from package **car** prints the ANOVA (Wald test) table for type II or type III, while R's standard `anova` function prints type I.

However, in case the design is balanced or you have only one independent variable, type I, II and III are the same:

```
> Anova(model, type="II")
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: y
          Sum Sq Df F value   Pr(>F)    
x           44.1  1    1323 4.57e-05 ***
Residuals    0.1  3                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> anova(model) # standard anova, type I
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
x          1   44.1  44.100    1323 4.57e-05 ***
Residuals  3    0.1   0.033                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

More about this can be found in statistics text books or for example at [www.r-bloggers.com](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/03/anova-%E2%80%93-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/).